# Define URL path segments in site edit wizard

Tags: web8

we want to add new domain using site edit wizard like http://www.Testsite.com. However in site edit wizard it is coming like sub domain. what are the configurations required to get new domain for publication.
For exapmle:Below is the TtmWebsite

```
BaseUrls             : {http://www.example.com}
CdEnvironmentId      : Preview_Environment
EnvironmentPurpose   : Preview
CdEnvironment        : 
ScopedRepositoryKeys : {Campaigns}
Id                   : Preview_Website
ExtensionProperties  : {}
```

when we are creating new publication using site edit wizard it is coming like http://example.com/testsite.

Thanks,
Ramesh

Comment: Leave it empty? The idea here is that you want people to create many (micro)sites and the only way to make it easy to achieve is through "sub paths" for the sites (typically, the /en-us language identifier or so). You can change this afterwards in Topology Manager if needed.

Comment: But it is not allowing us to leave it empty . How can i change this in Topology Manager ? Please provide commands for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why we use pre-defined domains, and allow editors to create a sub-path, is to stop people from thinking they can launch a completely new domain without registering it, and wondering why it didn't work...

So, in your example, assuming that you own the example.com domain, you could identify which of the new sites should have the URL www.example.com instead of www.example.com/somesite and, in PowerShell:

```
Set-TtmWebsite -Id Preview_Website -BaseUrls http://www.example.com
```

This will overwrite what is previously set in TTM to match this new URL. You still need to do your DNS homework, but Tridion will be fine with this.

Comment: For clarity: you get URLs like `http://example.com/testsite` from Site Wizard created Publications/Sites, because the Site Type is associated with a Website/app with Base URL `http://example.com` and it creates a Mapping with Relative URL `/testsite`.  If you already have a mapping for root level, the Site Wizard forces you to specify a distinct Relative URL for the Mapping.

Comment: This means that if you want to create Sites with a different Base URL using the Site Wizard, you will have to define a new Website in TTM, create a new Site Type and associate it with your new Website.

Comment: Hi Rick , Thanks for your answer. It is asking BaseUrls when creating new website using Add-TtmWebsite if we give base url www.testsite.com, again  it is creating sub-paths in site edit wizard . Can you please provide steps with example for create Sites with a different Base URL using the Site Wizard.

Comment: Hi Nuno Thanks for your answer, we have executed Set-TtmWebsite -Id Preview_Website -BaseUrls http://www.example.com command but how can we change PrimaryMappedUrl in Ttmmapping there is no parameter for PrimaryMappedUrl. Can you please provide steps for this.

Comment: That's exactly what Rick mentions in his comment - the PrimaryMappedUrl is determined by your "SiteType"